# Laravel: Why not work belongsTo()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I must print all messages with sender name in view. And I have model Inbox with this code:

```
protected $fillable = ['id', 'subject', 'message', 'sender', 'recipient', 'seen', 'show', 'trashed', 'created_at'];

public function sender() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sender');
}

public function recipient() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'recipient');
}
```

Where I return and print `$message->sender->name` given error `Trying to get property of non-object` and `$message->sender` = `sender id`. Using sender id I must get sender name from users table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose other names for these relationships because you have properties with the same names already.

```
public function messageSender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sender');
}

public function messageRecipient()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'recipient');
}
```

Or change column names to `sender_id` and `recipient_id`

Comment: And for get sender Name I must write in view  `$message->sender->name`?

Comment: @MaxNet `$message->messageSender->name`. But I would change column name to `sender_id`.